# Degeneracy of an energy level and Pauli Principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, pauli-exclusion-principle

I am a bit confused as to how these two concepts interact together. I'd like to discuss it with a simple example, that of the electrons in an atom. I am also not considering fine structure and HFS.

If we consider $n=2$, then $E_2$ is degenerated, and at most we have 8 electrons that have this energy. Now if we consider Pauli's Principe for an energy level we must have only 2 electrons with opposite spin. If we ignore as I said FS and HFS, how can do we explain this disparity ?

Edit:

I am also aware that an electron state is characterized by 4 quantum numbers, but if we were to look only at the first quantum number, wouldn't we get a contradiction regarding the degeneracy and Pauli's principle ?

Comment: You can't "ignore the other quantum numbers". The $8$ states are distinguishable by their angular momentum, so Pauli does not apply.

Comment: So in other words you're saying: "If we ignore the rules that allow this, wouldn't this be forbidden?"

Comment: Paulis Principle says :" You can't have 2 identical fermions in the same energy state". If you consider the quantum number n, then it looks as if you are having a contradiction, because all the electrons for an arbitrary n, are the same